# Deducing extent when passing std::array to function expecting std::span

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a function expecting a `std::span` parameter. This function is called by passing an `std::array`.
This works fine if the `std::span` argument is declared with template parameter `Extent` set to `std::dynamic_extent`. But if the function is templated on `Extent`, the compiler is unable to deduce this value from `std::array` argument.

*Any idea why the compiler is unable to deduce this template argument ?*

See the snippet code below ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/jf4T8TeKc)).

### Update after comments

When we explicitly create a `std::span` (**without specifying template parameters**) object when calling `g()`, everything works fine, the compiler is able to deduce the span type and `Extent` from the `std::array`. Following [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span), the corresponding constructor (5) is not mark as `explicit`.

*So why is the compiler unable to do the same deduction ?*

```cpp
void f(const std::span<std::byte> buffer)
{
    std::cout << "f() => Extent = 0x" << std::hex << buffer.extent
              << " Size = " << std::dec << buffer.size() << std::endl;
}

template<std::size_t Extent>
void g(const std::span<std::byte, Extent> buffer)
{
    std::cout << "g() => Extent = 0x" << std::hex << buffer.extent
              << " Size = " << std::dec << buffer.size() << std::endl;
}

std::array<std::byte, 4> buffer = {};

f(buffer);
g(std::span{buffer}); // <= Works fine
g(buffer);            // <= Compiler error!
```

With this result from compiler:

```
<source>:23:6: error: no matching function for call to 'g(std::array<std::byte, 4>&)'
   23 |     g(buffer);
      |     ~^~~~~~~~
<source>:13:6: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int Extent> void g(std::span<std::byte, _Count>)'
   13 | void g(const std::span<std::byte, Extent> buffer)
      |      ^
<source>:13:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:23:6: note:   'std::array<std::byte, 4>' is not derived from 'std::span<std::byte, _Count>'
   23 |     g(buffer);
      |     ~^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: the compiler simply cannot choose the extent for you. (it wouldn't compile for `void h(const std::span<T> buffer)` either)

Comment: Just `g(std::span{buffer});`.

Comment: You could add a helper: `template<class T> decltype(auto) g(T&& buffer) { return g(std::span{std::forward<T>(buffer)}); }`

Comment: If you make it a template, then why not simply use `auto& buffer`? What's the advantage of using `std::span`?

Comment: @eerorika: Because `span` has a particular interface, while `auto&` could be anything. By putting it in the function signature, it makes it clear that the type you provide must be a contiguous range convertible to a `span`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why is the compiler unable to do the same deduction ?

Because class template argument deduction is a different process from *function* template argument deduction.

In the case of `g`, the compiler has no idea what the constructors of `span` are because... it's not a class yet. It's a *template*. And since template specialization is a thing, it is entirely possible that the deduced `Extent` value radically changes what `span` conversion constructors are available.

Function template argument deduction is about matching the type of each function argument against the type and template parameters of the corresponding parameter type. Since you're using a specific template type whose arguments have to be deduced from those of the incoming parameter, this requires that the parameter be a specialization of that template.

Class template argument deduction bypasses all of this because it is *solely* based on the constructor declarations in the primary template (and any template deduction guides). It can use the constructors in that template to deduce the template parameters.

But function template argument deduction doesn't work that way.